# Android Using Firebase Analytics along with Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'd love to know how I can use Firebase Analytics (FA) and Google Analytics (GA) simultaneously as FA doesn't provide real-time data and my apps already integrated with GA since the beginning. I'd like to continue using GA since all my analytic data started there when I first launched my apps. Meanwhile, I'd like to have my apps have FA integrated to get more info.

I followed [Using Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics together](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en) and setup Google Tag Manager. It doesn't seem to be working for me. I do see FA dashboard being updated but nothing is showing up in GA.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide Tag Manager, Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics debug logs? Its really difficult to debug something with "its not working"  

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#logger

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#debugging

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use the google-services.json that is supplied for your app in the Firebase console. If this is missing your GA tracking ID, you can supply it manually either in your call to newTracker or as a string resource.

Comment: My JSON file is missing the GA tracking ID too. Do you know why this is the case? I've followed all the procedures to properly link GA to Firebase.

Comment: @Ian so if you're using Firebase config files. You'll have to supply your GA tracking ID in the code like this `tracker = analytics.newTracker(GA_TRACKER_ID);`

Comment: How about the manifest file? Do we need to add anything to it?

Comment: Nothing is needed into the manifest file. 
For me worked like this: Replace into your BaseApplication class mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker); with mTracker = analytics.newTracker(YOUR_ANALYTICS_ID);

Then replace "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        } 
into Firebase json file (google-services.json) with this: "analytics_service": { "status": 2, "analytics_property": { "tracking_id": "YOUR_ANALYTICS_ID" } },

Answer (score 3):

In FireBase console, don't CREATE NEW APP, just IMPORT GOOGLE APP.
Let import your current google analytic's app.
Then replace your old config file by new firebase's config file.
Enjoy!

Comment: share any sample off common xml firebase file

Comment: @influx I have added xml file from my Firebase project. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a sample of common XML/Plist taken from Firebase:**

**What I have done to obtain this file:**

1- Implemented Google Analytics for Android and created a project in Google API Console, then

2- Implemented Google Analytics for iOS linked to the same Google API project, then

3- Created Firebase Project based on the same Google API project.

XML Config file for Android:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "MYAPP_PROJECT_NUMBER",
    "firebase_url": "MYAPP_FIREBASE_URL",
    "project_id": "MYAPP_PROJECT_ID",
    "storage_bucket": "MYAPP_STORAGE_BUCKET"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "MYAPP_MOBILESDK_APP_ID",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "MYAPP_PACKAGE_NAME"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "MYAPP_CLIENT_ID_STARTING_WITH_PROJECT_NUMBER_1",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "MYAPP_PACKAGE_NAME",
            "certificate_hash": "MYAPP_CERT_HASH"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "MYAPP_CLIENT_ID_STARTING_WITH_PROJECT_NUMBER_2_DIFFERENT_THAN_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID_ABOVE",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "MYAPP_CURRENT_KEY"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "MYAPP_TRACKING_ID_FROM_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS"
          }
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Plist Config file for iOS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_BANNER_TEST</key>
    <string>MYAPP_AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_BANNER_TEST</string>
    <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_INTERSTITIAL_TEST</key>
    <string>MYAPP_AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_INTERSTITIAL_TEST</string>
    <key>TRACKING_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_TRACKING_ID</string>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_CLIENT_ID</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>MYAPP_CURRENT_KEY</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_PROJECT_NUMBER</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_BUNDLE_ID</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_PROJECT_ID</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>MYAPP_STORAGE_BUCKET</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <false/>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true/>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>MYAPP_MOBILESDK_APP_ID</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>MYAPP_FIREBASE_URL</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics side-by-side in both Android and iOS apps.

Comment: The problem is they both use google-services config json file that have different contents stored inside the json which is conflicting...

Comment: @Lancelot You should use the google-services.json that is supplied for your app in the Firebase console.  If this is missing your GA tracking ID, you can supply it manually either in your call to newTracker or as a string resource.

Comment: @SteveGanem, you resolved my issue! Please make your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: @Lancelot What did you do to get the GA tracking ID on your JSON file?