# Adding Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics in Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Firebase Analytics. It is working fine. I wish to use the Google Analytics as well. Based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715288/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-messaging-with-google-analytics-in-android) I have included the below object in the google-services.json

```
"analytics_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "analytics_property": {
        "tracking_id": "<your tracking id>"
      }
    },
```

For Google Analytics, I have the Tracker Class

```
public class PuzzleGamesTracker extends Application {

// The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "<your tracking id>";

private Tracker mTracker;


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

/**
 * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
 * @return tracker
 */
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

}

Usage

```
public void sendToGoogleAnalytics(String arg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sendToFireBase();
    PuzzleGamesTracker application = (PuzzleGamesTracker) getApplication();
    Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

    mTracker.setScreenName(arg);
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

}

public void sendToFireBase( ) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Test_Item 1A");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Test_Name 1A");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Test_Image 1");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Test_Item B");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Test_Name B");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Test_Image 1");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "Test_Item 2A");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Test_Name 2A");
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Test_Image 2");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

}
```

**Error Scenario**

If I did not include the below google analytics object in google-services.json, then the Fire Base is working properly.

```
"analytics_service": {
  "status": 2,
  "analytics_property": {
    "tracking_id": "<your tracking id>"
  }
},
```

When I include google analytics object in google-services.json, then i am getting this below error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [xml/global_tracker] C:\Users\android\build\generated\res\google-   services\release\xml\global_tracker.xml   [xml/global_tracker] C:\Users\android\res\xml\global_tracker.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

**Question**
1. Do I need to remove the ecommerce_tracker.xml and global_tracker.xml ? Already PuzzleGamesTracker class is using it . How to overcome it ?
2. Please guide me so that I could have both FA and GA implementation successful

Comment: why you implementing two same things?

Comment: They are not the same thing. I'm not OP but have the same problem. One of my clients asked me to add FireBase analytics while they already have Google Analytics in the app. They have their business reasons and the two should be able to work side by side, after all both are Google products as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer for adding both GA and FA

Step 1. Removed the xml files R.xml.global_tracker

Step 2. Replaced   mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker); with 
mTracker = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);

Step 3. Add the following in json file
"analytics_service": {
  "status": 2,
  "analytics_property": {
    "tracking_id": ""
  }
},

Comment: how about the app id in google-services.json? may I ask you how do you create your firebase project as well? I read an answer from other SO question about this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39323887/510577 which requires you to IMPORT GA APP instead of create a new app. Is it your case?

Comment: You need a Google Analytics ID, this is a different ID from Firebase project ID. Create a new project into Analytics website to get de "UA-XXXXXXXX-XX" ID.

Answer (score 0):

Looks cool, but what about App id, Don't we need app id for tracking events on both Google and Firebase Analytics

Comment: Should this be an answer or a comment?

Comment: This should be a comment, But I don't have permissions to write comments on others posts yet!!