# google-services.json for Firebase and Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services

I want to use Google Analytics and Firebase both in my project. I have downloaded google-services.json file from the Firebase console settings but after using it, I am not able to support Google Analytics. It is showing me the error:

```
Error:(463, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable global_tracker
```

How to configure both in same .json file?

Following field is missing from .json file downloaded from firebase dashboard.

```
"services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "analytics_property": {
        "tracking_id": "some_tracking_id"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Make sure that the package name in the google-services.json configuration file matches the package name you were using in the code. You can check it [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/26). You can also check this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078992/error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-xml-while-trying-google-analytics) which suggested that you need to create a new folder in your res folder called `xml` and move your file to that folder. Here's a [guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en) which might also help.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/MxB4Pk1DJmo

Comment: There is similar question that has a more complete answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370671/android-using-firebase-analytics-along-with-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

When I downloaded `google-services.json` from Firebase console, `analytics-service` looked like this:

```
"analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
```

However, since I have configured Google analytics as instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) using `global_tracker.xml` file, it seems there is no need to have it configured in the `google-services.json`.

Answer (score -3):

You should not use Google Analytics, Firebase already includes the analytics service that you could use better.

Just have in the module `build.gradle`:

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'`

Declare object

`private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;`

Instance in `onCreate` method

`mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);`

So register events:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("image_name", name);
params.putString("full_text", text);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("share_image", params);
```

More information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events

Comment: Disabling Google Analytics is not an option.